# improve existing VBA code to copy files faster

Tags: vba, excel

I am a google search coder on VBA.
I have a local folder in my PC with around 5000+ pdfs. 
I decided to sort pdf into folder which has the same names. the execution of the code is extremely lengthy as the code has to loop through 5000+ so that the sort happens accordingly. The below code works fine. I can live with it too.

Just out of curiosity I am posting this question, if there is a method to do this task at a faster rate.

```
Sub Create_FoldersAndExtractFiles()
    Dim sh1 As Object

    'for going through the files Dim FSO As Scripting.fileSystemObject Dim
    SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder, SubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim FileItem As Scripting.File
    fname As String

    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    'http://excelspreadsheetshelp.blogspot.com penAt = "My computer:\"

    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Please Choose The Folder For This Project", 0, OpenAt)

    'Set the folder to that selected. (On error in case cancelled)

    On Error Resume Next
    scr_Folder = ShellApp.self.Path

    'create the folders where-ever the workbook is saved

    lrow = sh1.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If lrow = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data to create the folder"
    Else
        For i = 2 To lrow
            fname = sh1.Range("a" & i)

            'to create a new folder
            If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fname, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir (scr_Folder & "\" & fname)
            End If

            'to move the file into a folder
            dst_folder = scr_Folder & "\" & fname

            Set SourceFolder = fso.GetFolder(scr_Folder)

            For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
                mname = Left(FileItem.NAME, InStr(1, FileItem.NAME, ".") - 1)

                If InStr(LCase(mname), LCase(fname)) Then
                    fso.MoveFile Source:=scr_Folder & "\" & mname & "*.*", Destination:=dst_folder
                End If
            Next
        Next

        Set FileItem = Nothing
        Set SourceFolder = Nothing
        Set fso = Nothing
    End If
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of that On Error Resume Next - is it masking any errors?

Comment: Is there a specific constraint that's forcing you to do this from inside Excel?  This looks like an easy XCopy candidate.

Comment: @ParrishHusband no there is no constrain. this is the method I know... any suggestion would help

Comment: If this code is working, it would be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your code loops for Number of Folders x Number of files.  That will be a _lot_ more than 5000 iterations.   Try to loop once to create the folders and then once to move the files.

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing the section (the loop)

```
        For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
            mname = Left(FileItem.NAME, InStr(1, FileItem.NAME, ".") - 1)

            If InStr(LCase(mname), LCase(fname)) Then
                fso.MoveFile Source:=scr_Folder & "\" & mname & "*.*", Destination:=dst_folder
            End If
        Next
```

with just this line:

```
fso.MoveFile Source:=scr_Folder & "\*" & fname & "*.*", Destination:=dst_folder
```